# How to run my kivy app in the background with a service file?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, pyjnius

I am building a kivy app and i want to run in the background or when using another app.

So far I do have a service file, but it doesn't seem to working. The app packaged perfectly without any errors, and the app did not crash. The buildozer.spec file is good. So can anyone please tell me where I went wrong.

Main.py -

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from plyer import accelerometer, spatialorientation, vibrator
from jnius import autoclass

spatialorientation.enable_listener()
accelerometer.enable()
time = 2

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 2
        self.accel = Label(text = "unknown")
        self.orien = Label(text = "unknown")
        self.add_widget(self.accel)
        self.add_widget(self.orien)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.service = autoclass('org.test.myapp.ServiceMyservice')
        mActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
        argument = ''
        self.service.start(mActivity, argument)
        self.grid = MyGrid()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 2/10)
        return self.grid

    def update(self, dt):
        accel1 = accelerometer.acceleration
        accel2 = (round(accel1[0], 2), round(accel1[1], 2), round(accel1[2], 2))
        new_accel = ', '.join(map(str, accel2))
        orien1 = spatialorientation.orientation
        orien2 = (round(orien1[0], 2), round(orien1[1], 2), round(orien1[2], 2))
        new_orien = ', '.join(map(str, orien2))

        if accel2[1] < 7 and orien2[1] > -0.65:
            vibrator.vibrate(time = time)
        else:
            self.grid.accel.text = new_accel
            self.grid.orien.text = new_orien


MyApp().run()
```

service.py -

```
from plyer import accelerometer, spatialorientation, vibrator, flash
from time import sleep

spatialorientation.enable_listener()
accelerometer.enable()
time = 2

def flashlight():
    flash.on()
    sleep(.2)
    flash.off()
    sleep(.2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        accel1 = accelerometer.acceleration
        accel2 = (round(accel1[0], 2), round(accel1[1], 2), round(accel1[2], 2))
        new_accel = ', '.join(map(str, accel2))
        orien1 = spatialorientation.orientation
        orien2 = (round(orien1[0], 2), round(orien1[1], 2), round(orien1[2], 2))
        new_orien = ', '.join(map(str, orien2))

        if accel2[1] < 7 and orien2[1] > -0.65:
            vibrator.vibrate(time = time)
            flashlight()
        else:
           sleep(.1)
           flash.off()
```

log script -

```
03-06 12:53:08.677 23341 28506 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
03-06 12:53:08.677 23341 28506 I python  : AND: Ran string
03-06 12:53:08.677 23341 28506 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
03-06 12:53:08.786 23341 28506 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
03-06 12:53:08.787 23341 28506 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
03-06 12:53:08.792 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-03-06_0.txt
03-06 12:53:08.792 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
03-06 12:53:08.792 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
03-06 12:53:08.792 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.9 (default, Feb 25 2022, 19:21:33) 
03-06 12:53:08.792 23341 28506 I python  : [Clang 8.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 40173bab62ec7462
03-06 12:53:08.792 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
03-06 12:53:08.793 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Analysing...
03-06 12:53:08.793 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
03-06 12:53:09.684 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
03-06 12:53:09.841 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
03-06 12:53:09.862 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
03-06 12:53:10.191 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
03-06 12:53:10.381 28518 28539 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
03-06 12:53:10.381 28518 28539 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
03-06 12:53:10.381 28518 28539 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
03-06 12:53:10.381 28518 28539 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app
03-06 12:53:10.381 28518 28539 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
03-06 12:53:10.381 28518 28539 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
03-06 12:53:10.381 28518 28539 I python  : calculated paths to be...
03-06 12:53:10.381 28518 28539 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
03-06 12:53:10.382 28518 28539 I python  : set wchar paths...
03-06 12:53:10.490 28518 28539 I python  : Initialized python
03-06 12:53:10.490 28518 28539 I python  : AND: Init threads
03-06 12:53:10.494 28518 28539 I python  : AND: Ran string
03-06 12:53:10.494 28518 28539 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
03-06 12:53:10.719 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
03-06 12:53:10.722 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
03-06 12:53:10.723 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r19p0-01rel0.###other-sha0123456789ABCDEF0###'>
03-06 12:53:10.724 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
03-06 12:53:10.726 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G72'>
03-06 12:53:10.728 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
03-06 12:53:10.731 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
03-06 12:53:10.734 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
03-06 12:53:10.800 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
03-06 12:53:10.803 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
03-06 12:53:10.995 23341 28506 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
03-06 12:53:10.995 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
03-06 12:53:10.998 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
03-06 12:53:14.076 28518 28539 I python  : Python for android ended.
03-06 12:53:19.769 23341 28506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
03-06 12:53:19.814 23341 28506 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main.py, define the service and start it:

```
from jnius import autoclass
SERVICE_NAME = u'{packagename}.Service{servicename}'.format(
    packagename=u'org.kivy.test',
    servicename=u'Myservice'
)
service = autoclass(SERVICE_NAME)
mActivity = autoclass(u'org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
argument = ''
service.start(mActivity, argument)
```

in buildozer.spec:

```
# (str) Package name
package.name = test

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.kivy

# (list) List of service to declare
services = Myservice:service.py
```