# Running Application even if it is closed

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I wrote an application using Python which receives data via Bluetooth, I need it to work even if it is closed. I can manage `on_pause` and `on_stop` functions by returning `True` or `False`. But when I added `on_pause`, `on_resume` and `on_stop` functions to my code, app does not continue receiving data (in the background and when it is closed), and restarts (`on_resume`). I need the application to work `on_pause` (in the background) and `on_stop` (when it is closed) and even when the user restarted his/her phone (and did not open it). And I read [I should use Services to run my app when it is not opened](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/). I use `buildozer` to debug my code, it is unclear to me, what I should add to my Python code and `buildozer`.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep kivy service running in background in Android (service still run when switch to other App or lock the screen)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218114/how-to-keep-kivy-service-running-in-background-in-android-service-still-run-whe)

Comment: Not exactly! I need the application work even it is closed! not just in background!

Comment: I do not know how to use `service` in my code. What I should write for `package_name` and `service_name`.
`service = autoclass('{}.Service{}'.format(package_name, self.service_name))
mActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
argument = ''
service.start(mActivity, argument)`

Comment: even [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367375/how-to-run-my-kivy-app-in-the-background-with-a-service-file)  did not help me. Maybe, because I am new in Kivy-android programming.